# need help in loading activity

Tags: android

I have created following activity

```
 package com.ali.test;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
/*
        OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

        }
    };
    */

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Second.class));

}
```

}

and want to load

```
                 package com.ali.test;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

   public class Second extends Activity{
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
  }
```

but when i press the buttons app closes unexeptionaly

Comment: Stacktrace please! Did you add the second Activity to you manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should Add secondActivity class in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".Second "></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the Second Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? here: [AndroidManifest.xml activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

It must be due to following:

1.check the button1 id in XML also..Both should match

2.Test Class and Second class must be defined in manifest..

Also do not forgot to 
Replace onClick with...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(Test.this, Second.class));

}
```

For more detail please specify the error